# How to specify for emacs tramp which remote shell to open?

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, zsh, tramp

Besides opening remote files, tramp can be used to run a remote shell. Unfortunately, there is a problem. On a local machine i have zsh and on remote server only bash is installed. Issuing M-x shell results in `exec: 24: /bin/zsh: not found` message.

Can I somehow tweak tramp to run bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try <kbd>M-x</kbd> `set-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `explicit-shell-file-name` <kbd>RET</kbd> `"/bin/bash"`<kbd>RET</kbd> - that should make <kbd>M-x</kbd> `shell` use bash from now on. Not sure if there's an easy way to switch depending on which machine you're on...

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't find that variable. For permanent effect one can put (setq explicit-shell-file-name "/bin/bash") in .emacs